# Каким членом предложения является глагол в данном предложении?

Tags: грамматика, члены-предложения

Хотел бы уточнить, каким членом предложения является глагол *провести* в следующем контексте (определением или же частью составного сказуемого?):

**Поехать в Марокко будет лучшим способом провести медовый месяц.**

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Глагол никак не может быть прилагательным. Возможно, Вы имели в виду *определением*?

Comment: Упс, небольшой казус вышел. Определением, конечно.

Comment: Я тоже люблю Марокко!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Поехать в Марокко будет лучшим способом провести медовый месяц.***

1. В грамматике  (Синтаксис современного русского языка. Учебник для вузов) сказано, что инфинитив в составном именном сказуемом является именной частью только **при наличии связки** в предложениях вида "Любить – это жертвовать собой".
   В таком случае это не часть сказуемого, а определение.

Для сравнения: желание (какое?) остаться (определение).

2. Из словаря: СПОСОБ,   (обычно с инф.). Возможность, средство, условия **для осуществления чего-л.** Найти лёгкий  с. заработать. Существуют разные способы жить достойно.
3. Похоже на **обстоятельственное определение:**  способ (какой?  для осуществления чего?) провести.  Провести (что?) медовый месяц (это дополнение).

Comment: С другой стороны, вопрос к дополнению медовый месяц задаётся именно от слова провести; а к дополнениям вопрос задаётся, насколько я знаю, от сказуемого.

Comment: Определением является только инфинитив, а от него задается вопрос к дополнению.

Comment: Похоже на то, потому что при изъятии части сказуемого предложение ломается.

Comment: В грамматике есть ПЕРЕЧЕНЬ вариантов для выражения ИМЕННОЙ ЧАСТИ. Про инфинитив я уже говорила. Есть еще вариант с НЕЧЛЕНИМЫМ СОЧЕТАНИЕМ. Примеры: мы были в трудном положении, камень был редкого сорта, она была девушка с характером, он хороший человек. Можно считать "способ провести время, способ заработать деньги, способ достойно жить и др."  НЕЧЛЕНИМЫМИ? Тогда они входят в сказуемое.  Других вариантов в грамматике нет.  Здесь точность определений  нужна, а не только личное мнение (я так считаю, а я так считаю). Иначе это будут не ответы, а беседа в чате.

Comment: *Поехать в Марокко будет лучшим способом.* Инфинитив можно изъять, предложение не ломается, поэтому мне ваш ответ кажется верным.

Comment: Я еще вот о каких примерах подумала. Поездка в Марокко будет лучшим способом для проведения медового месяца. Поездка в Марокко будет лучшим способом для того, чтобы провести  медовый месяц.  Слово способ требует обязательного распространения, но грамматика вариантов может быть различной.

Comment: @Sharon Минус. Обстоятельственное определение это определения в предложениях, вроде: ‟Уставший, он рано пошел спать” (‟уставший” является как характеристикой, так и причиной). Какое это имеет отношение к вопросу? Где здесь в вопросе такого рода определение?

Comment: @Sharon Только "лучшим способом проведения", без "для". А второй пример не нравится, "для того, чтобы" там не звучит. Здесь способ не для чего-то, а чего или что сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Когда инфинитив так относится к существительному, то он является несогласованным определением.
[Вот ссылка на статью (Несогласованные определения, пункт 5).](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/soglasovannye-nesoglasovannye-opredeleniya.html)

В сочетаниях: ‟желание учиться”, ‟стремление побеждать”, ‟способ победить”, ‟способ провести”, ‟мысль уйти” — инфинитив является несогласованным определением.

В данном предложении ‟будет способом” — сказуемое, ‟провести” — несогласованное определение, ‟медовый месяц” — дополнение.